# sql server table size check

Tags: sql-server

how to check size of tables of user defined database

Answer (score 1):

Try this, sp_spaceused 'Your_tableName'

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server Management Studio then you can check it by opening Object Explorer Details (press F7). Then click on Tables folder and find your table from list of tables. Once you click on your table you will find Data Space Used and Index Space Used in kilobytes. 
If you want proper explanation about checking size you can refer 
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81245/how-to-determine-the-size-of-my-tables-in-the-sql-server-database/81253

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
t.NAME AS TableName,
s.Name AS SchemaName,
p.rows AS RowCounts,
SUM(a.total_pages) * 8 AS TotalSpaceKB, 
SUM(a.used_pages) * 8 AS UsedSpaceKB, 
(SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages)) * 8 AS UnusedSpaceKB
FROM 
sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE 
t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255 
GROUP BY 
t.Name, s.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY 
t.Name
```